# Security question relating to executing server-side script

Tags: python, security, apache, server-side

I've written a python script using selenium to imitate a browser logging in and buying some stuff from a website.  Therefore, the python script contains log-in information along with payment information (checking account info, etc).  If i configure my apache webserver to be able to execute python scripts, so that when a client presses a button it runs my purchasing script, is there anyway that the client could see the contents of the python script (thereby gaining access to sensitive login and payment info)?

I remember reading that if an error occurs, the script would show up in plain text in the browser? Should I prevent this by using try and except blocks or is there a better method I'm not aware of?

Thanks for all your help in advance.

Comment: How are you running your python code? SSI, cgi, etc...?

Comment: Our server runs pythons files so I was just going to make a python system call like 'python pythonfile.py' from PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is usually a good idea to put such information in an external config file which can't be served by the webserver directly and read this file in your script. in case of a configuration error the client might see your sourcecode but not the sensitive information

Comment: Ok, thanks - that's a great idea.  When you say 'can't be served by the webserver directly', you mean that it is not called directly by the webserver (it's simply accessed by the called script) correct?

Comment: put it in a directory that is not in the DocumentRoot of your webserver, so there is no way a client can enter an URL that points to your configuration file. something like "/etc/yourapp/purchase.conf". your python script can read that, but apache cannot directly serve it.